# I want to change all the UIButton titles

Tags: uibutton

My xib file has many buttons, similar to a phone key pad.   I want to suddenly have all the keys to be randomly changed when a method like "randomizeAllButtons" is called.
Of course    setTitle: forState:UIControlStateNormal  works in a UIButton method, but I can't get it done from a separate method.
So much trouble trying to do this...  any ideas.

Comment: so, when you call setTitle:... it just does not do anything?

Comment: Can you post code from the separate method you have trouble with? If that problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Tag them (in Interface Builder, if you like). If you have 10 buttons, give them tag 0 to 9 or similar. That way you can get them via `UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];` and so on up to 9. Then it's just a matter of `[btn setTitle:@"Button 0"];` <-- this is all you need to write to set the title.

You can add them to an `NSMutableArray *btnArray` if you like, and jumble that - see docs.

You can do this in any method you like in the viewcontroller for the view with the buttons.

Comment: I had errors with that... combined the two statements awkwardly but it works... ' [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1] setTitle:@"anything" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2] setTitle:@"everything" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:3] setTitle:@"screw up" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:4] setTitle:@"put down" forState:UIControlStateNormal];'

Comment: There is some sort of bug in viewWithTag:0 as someone pointed out on a different post - 0 throws a crash -[UIView setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector ...   and if you start at 1 there is no crash... probably the same problem I had with the original answer's posting...  so I am working around this bug.

Comment: Well, I don't know about 0, but there are all kinds of positive and negative integers to choose from. Why do you need to use tag 0? Just add 10000 or something :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more generalized way to achieve your goal :

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        // change the title here ..
    }
}
```